# Building created with geometry nodes has sides and corners that won't line up

Tags: game-engine, geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

I have been following this tutorial for how to make a building using geometry nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-UqgJWwQ2U. I really love it but there's one problem I see with the corners. The corners overlap 2 meshes.
[image]

This isn't a problem in Blender but if I wanted to make this instance a solid singular object and import it into a game engine like Unity or Unreal, it might cause problems. I tried to modify the nodes from the video tutorial to make it so that the corners are omitted. My corner-less version works when you do the minimum 2x2 building:
[image]

And it works when I adjust the width:
[image]

But when I adjust the depth variable, the sides get out of alignment:
[image]

Can anyone help me get the sides to scale with no corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the original non-aligned depth geometry nodes:
[image]

This is the fixed geometry nodes:
[image]